# Create Multiple Authentication endpoints

Tags: grails, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have 2 separate objects (SystemUser, Customer) in my application and system user can be a customer. I would like to create a separate token end point for each object type. Currently, this is not supported by spring security core so I created a plugin for customer token endpoint. In this plugin I setup both spring security and oauth provider. I changed endpoint path as described in the docs. Here is my config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [

 '/customers/oauth/token':   ["isFullyAuthenticated() and request.getMethod().equals('POST')"]
]

// Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'Customer'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'Role'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.tokenServices.tokenEnhancerBeanNames = ['userDetailsTokenEnhancer']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.tokenServices.accessTokenValiditySeconds=60
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.tokenServices.refreshTokenValiditySeconds=120
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.defaultClientConfig.accessTokenValiditySeconds=60
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.defaultClientConfig.refreshTokenValiditySeconds=120

// Added by the Spring Security OAuth2 Provider plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.clientLookup.className = 'Client'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.authorizationCodeLookup.className = 'AuthorizationCode'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.accessTokenLookup.className = 'AccessToken'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.refreshTokenLookup.className = 'RefreshToken'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauthProvider.tokenEndpointUrl='/customers/oauth/token'
```

and I added the following section to my application spring security section: '/customers/oauth/**':['permitAll'],`

Both my application and customer plugin uses a shared domain plugin. The problem is that when I requested /customers/oauth/token I get 404 error any clue how to solve this?

Comment: I don't have answer to your question but I also faced a similar problem so I'll share my approach. I had a seller and a buyer in my application and both had to login to my app. I used standard spring security User Role for login endpoints and established one to one relation between User-Buyer and User-Seller. If possible, you can also go this way.

Comment: This approach will not work for me as in my case customer have specific attributes that admin shouldn't have. On the other hand admin can be a customer.

Comment: It does not matter at all. Spring security is concerned about User and Role class. Both admin and customer should have one to one relation with it and SS will have no problem with it. This way you will have same authentication endpoints.

Comment: what about switchuser functionality of spring security core plugin? https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/switchUser.html